# "Went" vs. "went along"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, idioms, phrasal-verbs

1. At work, he made up lies as he **went along**.
2. At work, he made up lies as he **went**.

Is one of those two wrong?

Comment: What's with the exclamation mark at the top of the question? Noting the difference in the revision.

Answer (score 4):

Either is correct, and in this context they mean the same thing.

Generally, "he went along" emphasizes the continuous act of going, spread out over time, whereas simply "he went" only draws attention to the fact that he went.  However, in your sentence, the word "as" makes them mean the same thing.  With or without *along*, "as he went along" means *during the time in which he was going*.

So there's a difference between *he went* and *he went along*, but there's little if any difference between ***as*** he went and ***as*** he went along.

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence would be:

> At work, he made up lies as he went along.

Both "went" and "went along" are correct, but "went" is the abbreviated version of "went along."  However, "go" and "goes" as you originally had, would not make sense in this tense.

Comment: So, ***went*** is wrong?

Comment: Both "went" and "went along" are correct, but "go" and "goes" would not make sense.

Comment: I can't see any justification for saying "went" is an abbreviation of "went along". They are just different phrases which in this case mean the same.

Comment: "went" is an abbreviated version of the phrase, I did not mean it was an abbreviation of the word itself.

Comment: Colin Fine, the point Alex Watson is making here (and is correct in doing) is that the full and proper form is "went along", where "went" is simply an example of ellipsis.

Comment: But it could also be an abbreviation of *he went to his boss* or *he went on his way*.  *He went* is simply broader (hence more ambiguous) than *he went along*, but it's not necessarily an abbreviated version.  It *is* ellipsis, but not necessarily elliptic of *he went along*.

Comment: I disagree this answer. OP's subject could quite reasonably say *"I'll make it up as I go."* Adding *"along"* is an optional addition just as much as something "expected" that you can optionally omit and assume to be implied.

Answer (score 1):

To my ear (I have no source), "as he went along" makes the lying it seem less purposeful or planned than "as he went".  Maybe it's just the informality of the language that creates that sense.

Comment: I think that's a spurious distinction.

Comment: If anything, Charles, I'd think the opposite of what you just assumed. It seems more purposeful, assuming I'd like to waste time and space partaking in banter for my own reasoning. Other words, I'm agreeing with @FumbleFingers